Microsoft Clarity logged "script error" JS
I recently installed Clarity on an Angular website using Google Tag Manager, and I'm encountering 100% of sessions with JavaScript errors. These errors include undefined functions, null properties, and more. However, the most common error is "script error," which accounts for 98% of the errors. Unfortunately, there isn't any further description provided for this error.I've reviewed all the records, and they each present a different scenario. How can I debug and identify this bug?
